# Extract results in code Lightswitch query

Tags: c#, visual-studio-lightswitch

I am new to C# and Lightswitch so my explanations may be somewhat convoluted, my apologies in advance.  I have a functional query (in code) that uses the _SingleorDefault method and returns a != null value.  In debug mode i can expand the 'Results View will enumerate the IEnumerable' and see the record that is returned along with the rest of the EntitySet.  How do i reference members of this set within the code?  This query does not return results to the screen so a Visual Collection methods return null values. Here's the query.

```
IDataServiceQueryable<DUTFullView> query;
        query = from DUTFullViewIDpass in this.DataWorkspace.AUTOData.DUTFullViews
                where (DUTFullViewIDpass.DUTTypeID == v.DUTTypeID)
                && (DUTFullViewIDpass.SN == v.SN)
                select DUTFullViewIDpass;

        if (query.SingleOrDefault() != null)
```

[Watch Window view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXdRe.png)

[Response to proposed solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edryF.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should iterate through with `foreach`

```
IDataServiceQueryable<DUTFullView> query = (from DUTFullViewIDpass in this.DataWorkspace.AUTOData.DUTFullViews
                where (DUTFullViewIDpass.DUTTypeID == v.DUTTypeID)
                && (DUTFullViewIDpass.SN == v.SN)
                select DUTFullViewIDpass).Take(1);

if(!query.Any())
    return;

foreach(var item in query)
{
    // You could do your logic here
    //var example = item.Property1
}
```

Comment: Tried your code example, but I cannot access the entities within the DUTFullView collection when i reference `item.`

Comment: To clarify i did not try to enter debug.  Using your code example...`foreach (var item in query)
{
    
    var localVar = item.xxxx}` where xxx should pull down a list of the entities within the DUTFullView collection.

Comment: It is possible that your query bring no data, and when hit the IF statement, then returns. You should check this, debugging the code

Comment: To clarify I added a screenshot for your reference in the original post

Comment: I have edited my answer to fetch the data before the foreach, try this.

Comment: The .ToList() method is not available to me when i append it per your example.  Not sure it's applicable...but I did some searching about converting the `query` structure to a list so that the method becomes available, but not sure how to format.